# Can't install Ubuntu 16.04 on a new machine - black screen

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

Just after choosing Install/Try Ubuntu getting black screen.
A moment before the black screen getting Error:

> Error parsing PCC subspace from PCCT
>
> ACPI Error: [INTS] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS....
>
> ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog....

and so on.

on:

```
gip-i7                      
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: System Product Name (SKU)
    vendor: System manufacturer
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=SKU uuid=A09AC97F-E2D7-DD11-A10D-107B44A33FA7
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: PRIME X299-A
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev 1.xx
       serial: 170705271600441
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1102
          date: 12/29/2017
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that work for me is move to 17.10
Installed without issues